# Relocate bash runtime files into arbitrary directory

Tags: bash, files, configuration

How do you relocate `bash` runtime files (`~/.bash_history`, `~/.bashrc`, etc.) to a defined directory (such as `~/.config/bash`, `~/.cache/bashhistory`, etc.)?

Comment: please refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/66117/where-to-put-custom-bashrc-stuff-in-bash-local , this may help

Comment: Make a feature request for XDG support. Dont let them tell you anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create symlink to your custom file

```
ln -s ~/.config/bash ~/.bashrc
ln -s ~/.cache/bashhistory ~/.bash_history
```

OR

For history file there is shell variable that you can set

```
HISTFILE=~/.cache/bashhistory
```

OR you can launch bash using :

```
bash --rcfile ~/.config/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single configuration option that would make Bash use
config files in a given directory.  You can use `--rcfile` to point
Bash to a given `.bashrc` as described in `man bash`:

```
   --rcfile file
          Execute commands from file instead of the standard
          personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is
          interactive (see INVOCATION below).
```

for example:

```
bash --rcfile ~/.config/bash
```

You can set `HISTFILE` shell variable to `~/.cache/bashhistory` in
`~/.config/bash`:

```
HISTFILE=~/.cache/bashhistory
```

And you can always create a symlink to a given file in ~/.config in
case of other config files, for example in order to able to edit
~/.config/profile instead of `~/.profile`:

```
ln -s ~/.profile ~/.config/profile
```

As a last resort, you could also set `$HOME` to `~/.config` and put all of the
config files with unchanged names in ~/.config and then just start bash
like that:

```
$ echo HOME_CHANGED=1 >> ~/.config/.bashrc
$ HOME=~/.config bash
$ echo $HOME_CHANGED
1
```

(Notice that `$` here is a [command line
prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)
used to indicate start of a new line, not a part of the command).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use links, you'll have to rebuild bash from source, patching the default path of ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile in shell.c.

Main drawback: you'll have to repeat this process periodically according to bash updates...